# Get embed URL through onedrive API

Tags: onedrive

Is there a way to get the embed URL through onedrive's API.

An embed URL is a publicly accessible URL that does not require a login since it contains an authkey.

I did manage to get the cid and resid, however, I can't figure out how to get authkey. Is there any way to get it?
I'm currently on onedrive's python SDK.

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `createLink` API to request an `embed` link.

```
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "type": "embed"
}
```

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online#creating-embeddable-links) for full details.

The SDK should also have `createLink` exposed so the above should map relatively easily into your use-case.

Comment: I did manage to get an object in response to the `https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf`. This object has a `refresh_token` and an `auth_token`. However, if I call  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` alongwith `'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token_for_graph,`, I get 
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "somerequestid",
      "date": "2019-01-23T06:37:14"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Also, since I am already using python sdk for one drive where I have managed to successfully upload a file using `client.item(drive='me', id='root').children['document_14_01_2019_3_36_PM.xlsx'].upload(
        './' + 'document_14_01_2019_3_36_PM.xlsx')`. Can't i use a similar approach to `createlinitem`?

Comment: @Abhilash, were you able to find a solution?